# Kafka Streams state restoration on Exception

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

With kafka streams we can do stateful operations. The state is kept local to the instance. This state is also backed up in a changelog topic, in case you lose your local state.

I saw that full state restoration also happens in case of an unhandeled exception in the streams application. Even if you use persistent storage.  Imagine if you have terrabytes of state and due a nullpointer exception, kafka will begin with the restoration of this huge amount of data. This will be very time consuming.

Why does kafka do a full restore of the state after an unhandled exception? Can we avoid this? Wrapping the code in a try-catch is not an option, because the message is then considered succesfully processed. We do some complex logic and also save some values in the state store.

Comment: Are you using EOS? -- `Wrapping the code in a try-catch is not an option, because the message is then considered succesfully processed.`: what behavior do you need?

Comment: Yes, we do use EOS. 
Lets say we do some computation and save something in the state store. In the next subtopology we do further post processing. When an exception occurs in here and if we do a try-catch, we need to rollback what we have saved in the previous subtopology.
If we do the processing without a try-catch, then nothing is saved in case of an exception, so no inconsistency issues here. But the downside is that upon restart, kafka will do a full state recovery (terrabytes of data). I did excpected that it will  recover the diff only, because the state is already persisted to disk.

Comment: For EOS, the current implementation requires to wipe out the state store to recover from an error -- otherwise correctness cannot be guaranteed. It's a know issues and there is a ticket for it: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-12549 -- You can use standby task for now to get quicker recovery until the ticket is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design the default is that runtime exceptions will stop your streaming process but you can control that to some extent using Exception Handlers -> https://developer.confluent.io/learn-kafka/kafka-streams/error-handling/

So you can for example send that specific message to a dead letter queue to process or check later what is wrong.

You can also configure the state store replication to avoid long / costly restoration times using `num.standby.replicas`, check -> https://kafka.apache.org/30/documentation/streams/architecture#streams_architecture_recovery

Good luck!